# CUSTOM SORT XSL?

Tags: xslt, sorting

This is my XML Structure like this

input :-

```
<MYDATA>
     <DETAILS>
       <DESCRIPTION>EASE</DESCRIPTION>
     </DETAILS>

     <DETAILS>
       <DESCRIPTION>COMPLEX</DESCRIPTION>
     </DETAILS>

     <DETAILS>
       <DESCRIPTION>SIMPLE</DESCRIPTION>
     </DETAILS>
</MYDATA>
```

I want to display like this using xsl sort it mean custom sort i want to display firts simple second ease and third complex

Output :-

```
<MYDATA>

     <DETAILS>
       <DESCRIPTION>SIMPLE</DESCRIPTION>
     </DETAILS>


     <DETAILS>
       <DESCRIPTION>EASE</DESCRIPTION>
     </DETAILS>

     <DETAILS>
       <DESCRIPTION>COMPLEX</DESCRIPTION>
     </DETAILS>

        </MYDATA>
```

Comment: You do know, that child elements are all the same level in XML. The element you get first depends on your XML parser. Some parse xml files bottom-up...so "SIMPLE" would be first in that case.

If you really need an sort order inside your xml you need to specify some sort of index (as attribute).

Comment: @fmuecke - WTF? XML is inherently ordered so you *don't* need to do this.

Comment: Is it really? I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: I'd like to see this solved, I need to sort using a list of types. I want to use a loop to make the code more element.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Jose's idea, here is something with less code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:variable name="DifficultyLevel">EASE|SIMPLE|COMPLEX|</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="MYDATA">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
      <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="string-length(substring-before($DifficultyLevel, DETAILS/DESCRIPTION))"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add data-type="number" to your sort, otherwise it will sort text-wise (e.g. 6 > 32)....

Answer (score 3):

There is a generic way to solve the problem.
What you need is to define a variable with the sorted list you want to use.
Then you use a recusive call to show the elements by that order.
Basicly you go by the elements of variable "sortOrder", applying then to a apply-template call that use that value the selects the node that you need.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


    <xsl:variable name="sortOrder">EASE|SIMPLE|COMPLEX|</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <MYDATA>
            <xsl:call-template name="SortElements">
                <xsl:with-param name="sortList" select="$sortOrder"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </MYDATA>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="SortElements">
        <xsl:param name="sortList"/>


        <xsl:variable name="element" select="substring-before ($sortList, '|')"/>

        <xsl:if test="$element != ''">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/MYDATA/DETAILS [DESCRIPTION = $element]"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="SortElements">
                <xsl:with-param name="sortList" select="substring-after ($sortList, '|')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DETAILS">
        <DETAILS>
            <DESCRIPTION>
                <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/>
            </DESCRIPTION>
        </DETAILS>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know what all the possible values you could do, you could do a series of condition-specific `apply-templates` calls:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Details[Description = 'Simple']" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="Details[Description = 'Ease']" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="Details[Description = 'Complex']" />
```

So if you know what order you want them in and the potential options aren't going to change, it will output them in whatever order your `apply-templates` rules are set.

Of course, if it's more complicated than that, you might consider storing sort order on the data side and include that in your XSL so you can just sort by that.