# XPath 1.0 lowest value regardless of ordering

Tags: xpath, minimum

I have this data, and I'm looking for the lowest bid.

```
<root>
    <current_bid>$1.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$2.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$3.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$4.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$5.00</current_bid>
</root>
```

This is my XPath 1.0 attempt:

```
 //current_bid[not(translate (., '$,.','') > translate(//current_bid, '$,.',''))]
```

And it works fine (returns only the $1.00 bid) with the data above, but if I change the ordering of the data to let's say this here:

```
<root>
    <current_bid>$5.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$1.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$2.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$3.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$4.00</current_bid>
</root>
```

Then it gives a wrong output (returns all values).

Shouldn't the order be irrelevant when I use //current_bid, since it queries the whole document?

Also: how would I go if I wanted the second lowest bid?

Answer (score 0):

XPath 1.0 processes nodes in document order so there's no way to sort them with pure XPath. It can be done with [XSL processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599470/custom-sort-xsl)
This approach works only if minimum is at first position.
Xpath:
`'//current_bid[(position()<=last()) and not(translate (., "$,.","") > translate(//current_bid, "$,.",""))]'`

Sample:

```
<root>
    <current_bid>$1.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$5.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$2.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$4.00</current_bid>
    <current_bid>$3.00</current_bid>
</root>
```

Testing on command line with xmllint

```
xmllint --xpath '//current_bid[(position()<=last()) and not(translate (., "$,.","") > translate(//current_bid, "$,.",""))]' test.xml ; echo
```

Result:

```
<current_bid>$1.00</current_bid>
```

If the number of nodes is known in advance perhaps it could be done with nested conditions but would give a very complex XPath expression.